# Gallery image is not display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create directive of magnific popup for photo gallery. My idea behind to create directive is that fetch and display gallery image from database by hzphoto directive and same data can use in directive so I don't require second call in database.

But I can get data successfully in hzPhoto and create array of data in hzMagnificPopup successfully but image is not displaying in template.

following is my code.

> Directive : hzPhotoDirective.js 
>  hzphoto : to get all photo from database
>   
>  hzImagepopup: to get record one by one in loop and store in array so later on I shall used for magnificpopup. Array is created successfully but image is not displayed in template.

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';


    angular
            .module("AppSigma")
            .directive("hzPhoto", [function () {
                    return{
                        restrict: "E",
                        replace: false,
                        template: "<div class=\"total_album_photo gallery\" ng-repeat=\"photo in list\"></div>",
                        scope: {
                            list: "="
                        },
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            console.log("scope list in hzpohot");
                            console.log(scope);
                        }
                    }
                }])
            .directive('hzImagePopup', ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
                    var arrData = [];
                    return{
                        restrict: "E",
                        //replace: true,
//                        template: "\n\
//    <div class=\"no_of_photo imgWrapper\">\n\
//        <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"popup-link\" data-index=\"2\" data-ref=\"{{photo.photo_name}}\" data-module=\"photo\">\n\
//            <img ng-src=\"/resize/photo/{{photo.photo_name}}\" height=\"120\" width=\"120\"/>\n\
//        </a>\n\
//    </div>\n\
//",
                        scope: {
                            list: "=",
                            link: "@"
                        },
                        compile: function (element, attrs) {
                            return{
                                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                                    console.log(scope.link);
                                    var originalImage_img = scope.link + "/" + scope.list.photo_name;                                   
                                    arrData.push({originalImage_img: originalImage_img});
                                    console.log(arrData);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }])
            .directive('hzImagePopup1', ["$rootScope", "HzPhotoService", function ($rootScope, HzPhotoService) {
                    return{
                        restrict: "A",
                        scope: {
                            list: "="
                        },
                        compile: function (element, attrs) {
                            return{
                                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                                    var module = 'photo';
                                    var data = [
                                        {originalImage_img: "/photo/2e94ab78daa337e448880d71250c4ec6.png"},
                                        {originalImage_img: "/photo/American-Brides-jewelry-Set-2015-Collection-For-Hot-Girls-3.jpg"},
                                        {originalImage_img: "/photo/cda82455689274565b94de46dc08d486.jpg"}
                                    ];
                                    var totalImage = data.length;
                                    angular.forEach(angular.element(".imgWrapper > a"), function (val, key) {
                                        console.log("index:" + angular.element(".popup-link").eq(key).data("index"));
                                        angular.element(".popup-link").eq(key).magnificPopup({
                                            key: 'my-popup',
                                            items: data,
                                            index: key,
                                            type: 'inline',
                                            verticalFit: true, // Fits image in area vertically
                                            inline: {
                                                // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
                                                markup: "\n\
<form class=\"white-popup-block ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope\" id=\"dataPopup\">\n\
    <div class=\"popup_heading\">Photo 1 of 3</div>\n\
    <div id=\"img_center\">\n\
        <img style=\"width:100%\" src=\"\" id=\"img_center_content\" class=\"mfp-originalImage\">\n\
    </div>\n\
    <button class=\"mfp-close\" type=\"button\" title=\"Close (Esc)\">×</button>\n\
</form>\n\
"
                                            },
                                            gallery: {
                                                enabled: true
                                            },
                                            callbacks: {
                                                open: function () {
                                                },
                                                change: function () {
                                                },
                                                markupParse: function (template, values, item) {
                                                    // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
                                                    // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
                                                },
                                                elementParse: function (item) {
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            console.log("photoloads");
                            console.log($rootScope.photos);
                        }
                    };
                }
            ]);
}());
```

> PhotoCtrl.js

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Photo Controller for photo features 
     * @param {type} $scope
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function PhotoCtrl($scope, $state, HzServices) {

        /**
         * Lists available albums of user
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        $scope.doAlbumList = function () {
            var data = {params: {q: $state.params.pid}};
            var deferred = HzServices.deferred("/api/album/list", data);
            deferred.then(
                    function (res) {
                        $scope.albums = res.data.album;
                        $scope.albumsCount = res.data.album.length;
                        $scope.photos = res.data.photo;
                        $scope.photosCount = res.data.photo.length;
                    },
                    function (res) {
                        $scope.albums = {};
                        $scope.albumsCount = 0;
                        $scope.photos = {};
                        $scope.photosCount = 0;
                    });
        };

        $scope.doGetPhoto = function () {
            return [{photos: $scope.photos, photoCount: $scope.photoCount}];
        }

    angular
            .module("AppSigma")
            .controller('PhotoCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'HzServices', PhotoCtrl]);
}());
```

> Photo.html

```
<div class="total_album_photo gallery" ng-repeat="photo in photos track by $index">
                                <hz-image-popup list="photo" link="photo" data-index="{{$index}}"></hz-image-popup>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a 2 days long efforts I had found my mistakes and I edited my code. I followed below way to resolve and issue and it's perfectly working to create dynamic pop-up gallery.

> photo.html

```
/*
 *  To create directive for loop through all gallery photos.
 */
<div class="total_album_photo_gallery">
    <hz-media-list photos="photos"></hz-media-list>
</div>
```

> photoList.html

```
/*
 * Here I can loop through all photos and display thumbnails of photos,
 * ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-stop to call directive in last photo,
 * so it will not call directive through all photos loop
 */
<div>
    <div class="total_album_photo gallery" ng-repeat-start="photo in photos track by $index">    
        <div class="no_of_photo imgWrapper">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup-link" data-index="{{$index}}">
                <img ng-src="/resize/photo/{{photo.photo_name}}" height="120" width="120"/>
            </a>
        </div>    
    </div>
    /*
     * Create magnific popup directive to show photo gallery it will fetch photos directly.
     */
    <div ng-repeat-end=""><hz-photo-popup></hz-photo-popup></div>
</div>
```

> HzPhotoService.js

```
/*
 * Create services to share common data to all directives.
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
            .module("AppSigma")
            .factory("HzPhotoService", ['$rootScope', '$state', 'HzServices',
                function ($rootScope, $state, HzServices) {
                    //$scope.sharedData = [];
                    return {
                        getPhotoData: function () {
                            var data = {params: {q: $state.params.pid}};
                            return HzServices.deferred("/api/album/list", data);
                        },
                        setSharedData: function (data) {
                            $rootScope.sharedData = data;
                        },
                        getSharedData: function () {
                            return $rootScope.sharedData;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]);
}());
```

> Photoctrl.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Photo Controller for photo features 
     * @param {type} $scope
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function PhotoCtrl($rootScope, $scope, $state, HzServices, HzPhotoService) {
        /**
         * Lists available albums of user
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        $scope.doAlbumList = function () {
            var data = {params: {q: $state.params.pid}};
            var deferred = HzServices.deferred("/api/album/list", data);
            deferred.then(
                    function (res) {
                        var data = {album: {count: res.data.album.length, data: res.data.album}, photo: {count: res.data.photo.length, data: res.data.photo}};
                        HzPhotoService.setSharedData(data);

                        $scope.albums = $rootScope.sharedData.album.data;
                        $scope.albumsCount = $rootScope.sharedData.album.count;
                        $scope.photos = $rootScope.sharedData.photo.data;
                        $scope.photosCount = $rootScope.sharedData.photo.count;
                    },
                    function (res) {
                        $scope.albums = {};
                        $scope.albumsCount = 0;
                        $scope.photos = {};
                        $scope.photosCount = 0;
                        var data = {album: {count: $scope.albumsCount, data: $scope.albums}, photo: {count: $scope.photosCount, data: $scope.photos}};
                        HzPhotoService.setSharedData(data);
                    }
            );
        }
    }

    angular
            .module("AppSigma")
            .controller('PhotoCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'HzServices', 'HzPhotoService', PhotoCtrl]);
}());
```

> HzDirective.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
            .module("AppSigma")             
            .directive("hzMediaList", [function () {
                    /*
                     * Photo thumbnail listing directive
                     */
                    return {
                        restrict: "AE",
                        replace: true,
                        templateUrl: "/views/photo/photoList.html",
                        scope: {
                            photos: "="
                        }
                    }
                }])                
            .directive("hzPhotoPopup", ["HzPhotoService", function (HzPhotoService) {
                    /*
                     * Magnific Popup directive
                     */
                    return {
                        restrict: "AECM",
                        replace: true,
                        scope: true,
                        compile: function (scope, element) {
                            return{
                                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                                    if (scope.$last) {
                                        var media = HzPhotoService.getSharedData();
                                        var arrData = [];
                                        angular.forEach(media.photo.data, function (value, key) {
                                            arrData.push({originalImage_img: "/photo/" + value.photo_name});
                                        });
                                        angular.forEach(angular.element(".gallery > .imgWrapper > a"), function (val, key) {
                                            angular.element(".popup-link").eq(key).magnificPopup({
                                                key: 'my-popup',
                                                items: arrData,
                                                index: key,
                                                type: 'inline',
                                                verticalFit: true, // Fits image in area vertically
                                                inline: {
                                                    // Define markup. Class names should match key names.
                                                    markup: "\n\
     <form class=\"white-popup-block ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope\" id=\"dataPopup\">\n\
     <div class=\"popup_heading\">Photo</div>\n\
     <div id=\"img_center\">\n\
     <img style=\"width:100%\" src=\"\" id=\"img_center_content\" class=\"mfp-originalImage\">\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"popup_main\">\n\
     <div class=\"popup_left photo_popup_left\">\n\
     <div class=\"popup_raw1\">\n\
     <div class=\"popup_raw1_left\">\n\
     <div class=\" location\">Location:&nbsp;<span>Ahmedabad</span></div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_link\">\n\
     <ul>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i>Like</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"popup_raw1_right\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">3 months ago</div>\n\
     <div class=\"clear\"></div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul ng-show=\"isAuth\" class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\">\n\
     <a style=\"padding-right:0px\" href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/dotimg.png\"></a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>Edit</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>Delete</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_main\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_img\">\n\
     <img src=\"images/latest-review-img.png\">\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_detail\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-left-name\">\n\ John Smith @johns\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">2 min ago</div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\">\n\
     <a style=\"padding-right:0px\" href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/dotimg.png\"></a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>Edit</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>Delete</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-text\"> What a hidden foodie haven! The ambiance is a relaxed with chic decor and healthy atmosphere. <a href=\"#\"> More (+) </a></div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_link\">\n\
     <ul>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i>Like</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-share-alt\"></i>Share</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_img\">\n\
     <img src=\"images/latest-review-img.png\">\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_detail\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-left-name\">\n\ John Smith @johns\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">2 min ago</div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\">\n\
     <a style=\"padding-right:0px\" href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/dotimg.png\"></a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-flag\"></i>Report</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-text\"> What a hidden foodie haven! The ambiance is a relaxed with chic decor and healthy atmosphere. <a href=\"#\"> More (+) </a></div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_link\">\n\
     <ul>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i>Like</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-share-alt\"></i>Share</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_img\">\n\
     <img src=\"images/latest-review-img.png\">\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_list_detail\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-left-name\">\n\ John Smith @johns\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">2 min ago</div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-right-row\">\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\">\n\
     <a style=\"padding-right:0px\" href=\"#\"><img src=\"images/dotimg.png\"></a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-flag\"></i>Report</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-text\"> What a hidden foodie haven! The ambiance is a relaxed with chic decor and healthy atmosphere. <a href=\"#\"> More (+) </a></div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_link\">\n\
     <ul>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i>Like</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-share-alt\"></i>Share</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_box\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_input\">\n\
     <textarea style=\"height: 76px;\" class=\"submitByEnter commentarea\" placeholder=\"Comment\"></textarea>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"comment_att\">\n\
     <div class=\"comment_btn\">\n\
     <input type=\"button\" value=\"Comment\" class=\"submit-btn button \"> </div>\n\
     <div class=\"latest-review-time\">\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul ng-show=\"isAuth\" class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\"><a href=\"#\">Attach</a></div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>Edit</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>Delete</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"popup_right photo_popup_right\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_detail_left\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_detail_img\">\n\
     <a href=\"#\"><img class=\"b4 border_none\" src=\"images/user_photo.jpg\"></a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"user_detail_name\">\n\
     <a href=\"#\">\n\
     <span class=\"header-full-name\">John Smith <br></span>\n\
     <span class=\"feature_header_username\">@john</span>\n\
     </a>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div>\n\
     <ul class=\"popup_menu\">\n\
     <li><a href=\"\">Share</a></li>\n\
     <li>\n\
     <div class=\"mgmenu_fixed mgmenu1\" id=\"mgmenu1\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"mgmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Mega Menu -->\n\
     <li style=\"border-left:0px\" class=\"username-menu\">\n\
     <div class=\"user_img_div\"><a style=\" color:#555555 !important\" href=\"#\">Actions</a></div>\n\
     <!-- Begin Item -->\n\
     <div class=\"dropdown_container user_menu_list_div dotmenu\">\n\
     <!-- Begin Item Container -->\n\
     <ul class=\"arrow_box_menu\">\n\
     <li><a style=\" padding: 5px 10px;\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></i>Edit</a></li>\n\
     <li><a style=\" padding: 5px 10px;\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i>Delete</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <!-- End Item Container -->\n\
     </li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     <!-- End Mega Menu -->\n\
     </div>\n\
     </li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"\">Remove</a></li>\n\
     <li><a href=\"\">Open Original</a></li>\n\
     </ul>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     </div>\n\
     <div class=\"video_main\">\n\
     </div>\n\
     <button class=\"mfp-close\" type=\"button\" title=\"Close (Esc)\">×</button>\n\
     </form>\n\
     "
                                                },
                                                gallery: {
                                                    enabled: true
                                                },
                                                callbacks: {
                                                    open: function () {
                                                    },
                                                    change: function () {
                                                    },
                                                    markupParse: function (template, values, item) {
                                                        // optionally apply your own logic - modify "template" element based on data in "values"
                                                        // console.log('Parsing:', template, values, item);
                                                    },
                                                    elementParse: function (item) {
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ,
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                            console.log("Shared data in link");
                            var sharedData = HzPhotoService.getSharedData();
                            console.log(sharedData);
                            console.log("=============================");
                        }
                    }
                }]);
}());
```

Above efforts and code modifications resolve my issues, but I welcome and appreciate optimized answer.